# Methods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, methods

I have 2 classes in Swift in different Swift files, and I'm trying to call a method from the other class, and pass an integer as an argument. I have the following:
Class 1:

```
Inschatting.wentBack(Punten)
```

Class 2:

```
class Inschatting : UIViewController {
    var Punten:Int = 0;
    @IBOutlet var inschattingAdvies: UILabel!

    func wentBack(Punten:Int) {
        self.inschattingAdvies.text = Punten
    }
}
```

Given error: Cannot convert value of type "Int" to expected argument type 'Inschatting'

Bonus question: Class 2 also complaints about the fact I want to put down a String, but it's clearly an Int

Comment: 1. You seem to be trying to invoke the `wentBack` function on the class rather than on an instance. 2. Why would you think you could simply assign an Int to a String (presumably `self.insChattingAdvies` is a UILabel or a UITextField)

Comment: Call it "I still need to learn Swift because I just finished an Android project", but isn't this how I call upon a function inside the class?

Comment: Even in Java you can assign an Int to a String.  And if you program Java you should also know the difference between an object class and an object instance

Comment: * cannot assign an Int to a String. @Paulw11

Comment: Doh. Yes. Cannot was meant!

Answer (score 1):

When you want to call your wentBack()-Func like above you should declare it as a class function... otherwise you should create an instance of Inschatting.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that Inschatting should declare the function the following way:

```
  static func wentBack(Punten:Int) {
        self.inschattingAdvies.text = Punten
    }
```

But the problem is that, that you have an instance value the wentBack function.

```
self.inschattingAdvies
```

Now what you need to do is to make a decision:
 1. you should call the wentback function on a Inschatting instance.
   In Class A:

```
 let instance = Inschatting()
 instance.wentBack(5)
```

2. You should remove the self.inschattingAdvies from wentBack.

Answer to your bonus question:

"Punten" does not seem to be an integer, or an enum value at all to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Inschatting` class is a `UIViewController`, I suspect you want to display the data from your 1st class in your `UIViewController`. If this is indeed true your mistake is that you are using a Class instead of an instance of the class.

If you indeed want to display the data from your 1st class in your 2nd class (The VC), you will need to create a class instance of your second class.

```
let inschattingVC = Inschatting()
```

this way you can use `inschattingVC.wentBack(someRandInt)` to call your function and set the text accordingly.

Secondly your `Punten` in `Inschatting.wentBack(Punten)` is also probably not a variable but again an instance (or you should rename it. Variables should start with lowercase letters!!!).

So if you are creating a class instance using `Inschatting()` you should be able to use `.wentBack(12345)` to set the text in your class instance.

Answer (score 0):

First you say :

```
 @IBOutlet var inschattingAdvies: UILabel!
```

so inschattingAdvies is a `UILabel`
Then you have a function :

```
func wentBack(Punten:Int) {
        self.inschattingAdvies.text = Punten
    }
```

where you have Punten which is an integer. And then you try to set the **text** property of your label to punten.
Your code should be :

```
func wentBack(Punten:Int) {
        self.inschattingAdvies.text = String(Punten)
    }
```

note the cast to a string.
Not sure if that's the error you were getting, but it's definitely also an error.